# Xpath changing after each run

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Could someone help, please.

I need to grasp a number that's generated after each run. As this number changes after each run, I need to grasp it and write it to excel sheet. I'm using `Xpath` for this field but not sure how to make this field more generic so that it only catches the number that is generated last.

The `Xpath` I tried is shown below and the syntax that is changing is `div[2]` to `div[3]` :-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/section/section/article/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/p")).getText();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/section/section/article/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/p")).getText();
```

My HTML SOURCE code is :

```
 <div class="card-details row"> <div class="pane base4"> <div class="card"> <div class="card-name"> <div class="card-number"> <h4>Card number</h4> <p>633597015500042861</p> </div> <a class="submit-btn uniform-button button-smaller button-orange" href="/my-account/replacement-card?cardId=1ce25b86-27e6-4ce8-8ef3-6576f9a0ae84"> </div>
```

Thanks and Regards, 
Az.

Comment: Could you share your HTML code??...

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you with appropriate answer if you share the HTML code of the text you are looking for. Also, using relative xpath is suggestible over using absolute xpath. If you can please share the HTML code, we can help you with efficient xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use below xpath to retrieve the card number.

```
String cardNum = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='card-number']/p")).getText();
```

You are accessing the randomly generated card number from the `<div class="card-number">` tag.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
//h4[contains(text(),'Card number')]/following-sibling::p
```

or

```
div[h4[contains(text(),'Card number')]]/p
```

if occurrence of same xpath more than once in your code and you want to select the last one following is the way:

```
xpath[count(sameXpath)]
```

this will give you the last occurence of the xpath

Answer (score -2):

Please do it like below:

```
// as per your given xpath 
    String FirstXpath = "/html/body/div/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/section/section/article/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[";
    String SecondXpath = "]/div[1]/div/div[2]/p";

// make sure here i value is as per your application
for(int i=2;i<4;i++){
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(FirstXpath + i + SecondXpath)).getText();
}
```

Just make sure value of `i` as per your div value change.

### Update

As per html provided `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='card-number']/h4/p")).getText();`.

Comment: This isn't a good solution. It will throw an ElementNotFoundException 100% of the time as you are always searching for both of the possible xpaths. Even if you would catch this exception it is most likely still an overkill solution as it shouldn't be needed to find an element by traversing the DOM for the html tag to the elements, but that is something the asker should figure out.

Comment: Hi All, each time a new card is generated and I need to catch the last card number generated know that after each run a new card is created. the html code is:  <div class="card-details row">
<div class="pane base4">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-name">
<div class="card-number">
<h4>Card number</h4>
<p>633597015500042861</p>
</div>
<a class="submit-btn uniform-button button-smaller button-orange" href="/my-account/replacement-card?cardId=1ce25b86-27e6-4ce8-8ef3-6576f9a0ae84">
</div>

Comment: @ RemcoW First of all it is not going to throw error ElementNotFoundException ,secondly please read carefully FirstXpath and SecondXpath will always remain constant they will never change (please compare two xpaths provided by the OP) only value of i will change form 2 to 3 i.e changing div[2] to div[3].and lastly xpath is as provided Thanks

Comment: Thank you All four your response but i keep getting the first card number generated and not the last one. So far I have 6 different card numbers generated randomly but I need to catch the last card number generated know that every time I run the script I get new card number. Thanks.                                                                                                        Note: Is there a way where I can attach screenshot in here?.

Comment: @Prady: Please give more details on how this xpath[count(sameXpath)]  is used.

Comment: I'm still looking to find a solution to the issue I'm having above. I need to know how can I capture the last xpath element after counting.  The code below used  to count the number of xpath elements                                                                                                             int xpathCount= driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='card-number']")).size();

Comment: if above xpath worked and gave u the size of the xpath then do it like below as u want to select last value so use xpathCount.get(xpathCount.size()-1).getText();